# Produce text on random page visit/refresh

Tags: php

Maybe PHP isn't enough here (JavaScript?), but my aim is this:

I want a bit of HTML to show on a page at random, with a chance value I can adjust (1 in 10000, 1 in 1000, etc.) The end result should be after so many refreshes/visits to the page, the HTML will show; my hope is the user will feel it's a random occurrence.

Honestly, I couldn't even articulate this query to Google or StackOverflow or any site to produce a response even close to my desires. I'm also still a novice in PHP, so it didn't help the search.

Comment: Where is the code when it is not random.

Comment: A common counter-question on SO.
`What have you tried so far?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a random number.

```
$randomNumber = mt_rand(0, 100);
if ($randomNumber === 0) {
    echo 'This will be echoed on average once every 100 times';
}
```